# Bind WPF combobox submenu item to combobox selecteditem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Inside this combobox I have a menu that contains multiple menus.

This is how it looks:

[image]

This is the XAML:

`<ComboBox>
      <Menu>
         <MenuItem Header="Name">
                   <MenuItem Header="Last" />
                   <MenuItem Header="First" />
         </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      <Menu>
         <MenuItem Header="Age">
                   <MenuItem Header="20" />
                   <MenuItem Header="24" />
         </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
 </ComboBox>`

When the user selects "Last"/"First"/"20"/"24" I want the combobox to set its selected item to one of this 4 items.

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. But I am not sure if this is the best way cos I dont know your requirement in full.

XAML:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmb1" IsEditable="True" >
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem Header="Name" >
                    <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" CommandParameter ="Last" Header="Last"/>
                    <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" CommandParameter="First"  Header="First" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem Header="Age">
                    <MenuItem Header="20" />
                    <MenuItem Header="24" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </ComboBox>
```

vb Code:

```
 Private Sub MenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Me.cmb1.Text = CType(sender, MenuItem).CommandParameter.ToString()
 End Sub
```

c# code :

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    this.cmb1.Text = menuItem.CommandParameter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: in C# it's `this`. @voddy